# Unicode character folding with Swiper/Ivy

Tags: search, isearch, ivy

Suppose I have `bár` written in a file, I would like to look for `bar` in `swiper` and find the occurrences of `bár` alongside the expected occurrences of `bar`, how I can do this? This would also apply to characters like e=é=è, o=ö, u=ü, a=å, o=ó=ö, c=ç, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `bar` match `bár` is called character folding, and is supported by the built-in functions `isearch` and `query-replace` since Emacs 25; see [`(emacs) Lax Search`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lax-Search.html) and [`(emacs) Search Customizations`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search-Customizations.html) for details.

`swiper` automatically performs character folding when `search-default-mode` is set to the function `char-fold-to-regexp`, which you can achieve by e.g. adding

```el
(setq search-default-mode #'char-fold-to-regexp)
```

to your `user-init-file`. Voila:

[image: char folding]

Comment: That worked for swiper, but for some reason it did not work with ivy-bibtex.

Comment: @k76u4vkweek547v7 That is because the `char-fold-to-regexp` integration is specific to the [regexp builder](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#completion-styles) for `swiper`. Feel free to submit a feature request on the project's issue tracker: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues.

Comment: @k76u4vkweek547v7 Adding to that, one solution is to use that re-builder for `swiper`, i.e. `(setq ivy-re-builders-alist '((ivy-bibtex . swiper--re-builder)))`