Make Swiper ignore diacritics
Using swiper, I want to search a spanish buffer for the word: "análisis".
However, if I type: analisis (no diacritics); swiper says the word is not available.
How can I set swiper so that when I type: "a" will search for all the possible diacritics for "a" (e.g.: á, à, â, etc)

I don't know what swiper does, but if it uses isearch underneath, then you can try customizing isearch-regexp-function to char-fold-to-regexp.

Sorry, make that search-default-mode

Hello @rpluim. You are a life saver. Would you mind making your comment an answer so that I can mark it as correct? Thanks in advance

I have found this post that answered my question previously: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42107/unicode-character-folding-with-swiper-ivy
I was not familiar with the term 'Character folding'. Feel free to mark my question as a duplicate.

Does this answer your question? Unicode character folding with Swiper/Ivy
